# Javascript - Getting dynamic name from HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I need to figure out how to make my javascript take in the select names dynamically. How should I go about this?

I've tried Tried var i = getElementsByName() and then if (i == "x) ... else .... with no results

My Javascript:

```
function displayResult()
{
   var m=document.getElementsByName("x");
   document.getElementById('divid').innerHTML = m[0].value;
}
```

My Html:

```
  <form>
       <select name = x>
         <option> a </option>
         <option> b </option>
         <option> c </option>
       </select>
       <select name = y>
         <option> 2 </option>
         <option> 3 </option>
         <option> 4 </option>
       </select>
     </form>
```

Comment: @pure_code Need document.getElementsByName("x"); to get the names dynamically

Comment: do you mean you want "x" to be a variable?

Comment: Obligatory : What have you tried?

Comment: @AshwinMukhija Tried var i =  getElementsByName() and then if (i == "x) ... else .... No results

Comment: The "ByName" in  getElementsByName() referrers to the element name (like `<select>` or `<form>`) not the name attribute.  In case that helps.

Comment: @JasonSperske No it does not. If I use the code as is, itll work.

Comment: So... you want to pass the name as variable to `displayResult`? Or do you want to get all `select` elements which have a name? How'd do you choose the one to get the value from then? Your question/problem is not clear, please provide more information. Maybe it's also an XY problem. How/when is `displayResult` called? What are you really trying to do? The more relevant information you provide, the better answers we can give.

Comment: @JasonSperske You're probably confused with `.getElementBy**Tag**Name()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need that x to be 'dynamic'. I don't really understand what you mean with that but I guess you want to specify another name every time you call the function. That's what function parameters are for.
Change your function to this:

```
function displayResult(name)
{
   var m=document.getElementsByName(name);
   document.getElementById('divid').innerHTML = m[0].value;
}
```

Now you can call the function with:

```
displayResult("x");
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I dont know why I didnt think of it this way. So simple. Long day at work...

Comment: Do note that if you have more elements with the same name this method only sets the first. If you need all of them you should change the function to include looping over all these elements, if you want to decide that on every function call add a second parameter to use as the array index. @JeftLebowski

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be with jQuery http://jquery.com

```
var myx = "x";
var elems = $("select[name=" + myx + "]");
```

Also with new browser APIs using pure Javascript:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("select[name=x]")
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll

Comment: X needs to be dynamic. We dont know if its gonna be x, y, z or what

Comment: Updated the answer. You can dynamically create strings in Javascript.

Comment: If you are not familiar dealing with strings in Javascript I suggest you study Javascript basics as the scope of the additional question is in the learning the programming language basics http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are actually looking for is this:

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
var names = new Array();
for(i=0,c=nodes.length;i<c;i++){
    names.push(nodes[i].name);
}
```

this code will produce an array `names` containing the names of selects presented on the page